# What is the "persistence domain model"

Tags: java, hibernate

I see a lot of references to this in Java software discussions specifically those talking about Hibernate.  I cannot find any definition of what it is and why I care about it.  Any one got a good definition for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look up Domain Driven Design (DDD). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design
The persistence part is simply, that it is capable of persisting (storing its state) which can be done somewhat painless with an OR mapper like Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that by Persitence Domain Model, what is actually meant is the ActiveRecord Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern whereby your domain model reflects your database scehma.

However, this is desribed as a Persitence Domain Model when Active Record lies underneath your actual Domain model.  Thus the ActiveRecord classes serve to perform actions on your database, but you don't expose them to other parts of your application (i.e. they're accessed by your domain objects)

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that it is simply the set of classes whose instances have state which must persist across sessions.